# MySQL hangs when query is run. How can I make this more efficient?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

We are trying to run a query to get all unpaid invoices.  When I run the query it hangs our whole system.  I am just wondering if there is a way I can make this more efficent.  SQL isn't my strong point.
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.order_id, o.*, acct.*, (SELECT SUM(items.item_qty) AS qty FROM items WHERE items.order_id = o.order_id ) AS order_qty
                FROM items AS i
                INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = i.order_id
                INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.order_id = o.order_id
                INNER JOIN accounts AS acct ON o.acct_id = acct.acct_id
                INNER JOIN ship_to AS st ON o.ship_id = st.ship_id
                WHERE o.order_status=7 AND o.order_date > '2009-05-01 00:00:00'
 AND (SELECT SUM(items.item_price) AS price FROM items WHERE items.order_id = o.order_id) * (SELECT SUM(items.item_qty) AS qty FROM items WHERE items.order_id = o.order_id) + o.order_ship_amount-(SELECT sum(trans_amount) FROM transactions WHERE t.order_id = o.order_id AND trans_pending = 0)!=0
 AND acct.is_wholesale=1 
            GROUP BY o.order_id
            ORDER BY o.order_date
            LIMIT $offset, $limit";
Here is the table layout information for the needed tables:

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `scat_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `inv_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `item_qty` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `item_price` float(10,3) NOT NULL default '0.000',
  `item_mfg` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `item_group` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `item_ship_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`item_id`),
  KEY `prod_id` (`prod_id`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `inv_id` (`inv_id`),
  KEY `scat_id` (`scat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=834659 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `acct_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `order_confirm_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_approval_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_deposit_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_sent_to_mfg` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `order_due_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_ship_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_exp_ship_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `order_ship_type` text NOT NULL,  
`order_ship_amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `order_mfg_name` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `order_status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ship_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `bill_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_requested_quote` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_submitted` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_origin` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_po_no` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
 `qd_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `order_inactive` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `order_cancelled` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`order_id`),
  KEY `ship_id` (`ship_id`),
  KEY `bill_id` (`bill_id`),
  KEY `acct_id` (`acct_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20311622 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `trans_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `trans_pnref` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_card_type` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trans_amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `trans_type` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_tender` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_po_no` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_origin` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_rep` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `trans_po_received` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trans_inactive` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `trans_pending` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `trans_secured` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`trans_id`),
  KEY `cod_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=211554 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `acct_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `acct_signup` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `acct_first` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_last` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_company` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_email` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_email_cc` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_email_bcc` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_phone` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_fax` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_password` text NOT NULL,
  `acct_default_ship` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `acct_default_bill` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `is_account` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `is_wholesale` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `tpsg_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`acct_id`),
  KEY `acct_default_ship` (`acct_default_ship`),
  KEY `acct_default_bill` (`acct_default_bill`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`),
  KEY `tpsg_id` (`tpsg_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=264476 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CREATE TABLE `ship_to` (
  `ship_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `acct_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ship_first` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_last` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_company` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_address1` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_address2` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_city` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_state` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_zip` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_country` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_phone` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_fax` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `ship_inactive` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ship_id`),
  KEY `acct_id` (`acct_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=241339 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

What I want this query to do is to pull the order information for all orders that have a status of 7 are after May 1, 2009 and add up the prices for all items in the order multiplied by the quantity then add the shipment amount and and subtract from it the amount paid and check if it's not 0.Also, the account has to be a wholesale account.  
I know this query is very inefficient but I am not sure how else to do it.  Our system is so overwhelmed it is very laggy in general.
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   
    o.order_id,  
    o.order_ship_amount,  
    SUM(i.item_qty * i.item_price) AS item_amount,  
    (   SELECT SUM(trans_amount) FROM transactions
        WHERE order_id = o.order_id AND trans_pending = 0
    ) AS trans_amount,
    ... etc.
FROM  
    orders AS o  
INNER JOIN accounts AS acct ON o.acct_id = acct.acct_id  
INNER JOIN ship_to AS st ON o.ship_id = st.ship_id  
INNER JOIN items AS i ON o.order_id = i.order_id  
WHERE   
    o.order_status = 7   
    AND o.order_date > '2009-05-01 00:00:00'  
    AND acct.is_wholesale = 1   
GROUP BY o.order_id  
HAVING item_amount + order_ship_amount - trans_amount != 0  
ORDER BY o.order_date
```

Comment: This works.  However if there is someone who hasn't made any transactions at all. trans_amount will be NULL and therefore wont return anything even they technically have a balance.   Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Ooops...Fixed that with addding OR trans_amount IS NULL

Comment: Or, use

IFNULL(SUM( ... ), 0) AS trans_amount

Answer (score 1):

Use explain to analyze query execution plan:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html  and  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html

In general subqueries in WHERE are very slow, try to rewrite them as JOIN.

Comment: I did the explain and all keys and indexes seem to be correctly set in the tables.

Comment: It would be usefull to see output of EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

It is the subqueries in the WHERE clause.  Naktibala hit the nail on the head there...

You can also try to create some temporary tables for the data you are getting for your subqueries.  Basically, put the data you will need to temp table(s), then JOIN those table(s) normally to your base query.  Once that all works you can streamline/tweak.

Answer (score 0):

As you allready join items and transactions by order_id,
I think that you can drop your subquery condition, and move checks to HAVING.

Try running this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS i.order_id, o.*, acct.*, SUM(items.item_qty) AS order_qty
FROM items AS i
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = i.order_id
INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON t.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN accounts AS acct ON o.acct_id = acct.acct_id
INNER JOIN ship_to AS st ON o.ship_id = st.ship_id
WHERE o.order_status=7 AND o.order_date > '2009-05-01 00:00:00'
AND acct.is_wholesale=1
GROUP BY o.order_id
HAVING ( SUM(items.item_price) * SUM(items.item_qty) + o.order_ship_amount - SUM(transactions.trans_amount) ) != 0
ORDER BY o.order_date
LIMIT $offset, $limit
```

Comment: Just noticed that o., acct., isn't valid SQL syntax

Comment: Yea for whaetever reason on the copy/paste it didn't show the *

Answer (score 0):

See if this describes your query a little more simply
(and isn't a bit more efficient.)

```
SELECT   
    o.order_id,  
    o.order_ship_amount,  
    SUM(i.item_qty * i.item_price) AS item_amount,  
    SUM(trans_amount) AS trans_amount,  
    ... etc.
FROM  
    orders AS o  
INNER JOIN accounts AS acct ON o.acct_id = acct.acct_id  
INNER JOIN ship_to AS st ON o.ship_id = st.ship_id  
INNER JOIN items AS i ON o.order_id = i.order_id  
LEFT JOIN transactions AS t ON t.order_id = o.order_id  
    AND trans_pending = 0  
WHERE   
    o.order_status = 7   
    AND o.order_date > '2009-05-01 00:00:00'  
    AND acct.is_wholesale = 1   
GROUP BY o.order_id  
HAVING item_amount + order_ship_amount - trans_amount != 0  
ORDER BY o.order_date
```

Make sure you can read and understand it - I haven't tested it.

Comment: It worked a little better however...Its summing the overall transaction amount for ever line item on the order.  So if it has 5 items in the order the transaction about will be 5 times higher than it should be.  Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Fixed and added as another answer. Joining on multiple one-to-many links will screw up your row counts, so I moved the trans sum into a subquery (but an efficient one; i.e. not correlated.)